# Excel Macro for multiple filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a excel macro which require to get the input from user from the particular column and then filter the value based on user input.

Note:

1) The input should prompt for list box that will show all the values present in that column.
2) User can select multiple value one or more.
3) Based on user input filter the sheet and display the result.

Experts in Macro can you please advise.

I tried since the input values from user is dynamic(one or more selection) I am facing the challenge.

Range("B2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("Selection1","Selection2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: why don't you use excel UI built in filter features? (you should find them under "Data -> Sort and Filter"

Comment: Hi, I want to do it using macro..

Comment: are you using Userforms? Give more details about your user interface

Comment: yes I am using user forms but how to get the value once user click ok button and do the filer in excel column based on listbox selection in user form

Answer (score 2):

Your `Range` needs to be for the entire table which you wish to filter and use the `Field` parameter to specify which column to filter. e.g. `Range("A1:D50").AutoFilter Field:=2` will filter the B column for a table spanning from cells `A1` to `D50`.

Set your filter values before the AutoFilter line, this will also make it easier for you to build your dynamic feature to specify the filter values. e.g.

```
filterValues = Array("Criteria1","Criteria2", "Criteria3")
Range("A1:D50").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filterValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

In order to get input from a user to populate the `filterValues` array you will need to build a userform for this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have more criteria in autofilter, you should give them separately. I have not seen excel taking it as an array. Separately like this:

```
Sub Makro2()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="123"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="122"

End Sub
```

Comment: it will take it in array.. I tested it's working... but I want if there is more than one .. where we user input count is dynamic what to be done for that case.

Comment: So, if your question is how to take the user input dynamically, then the answer is - use events. Like this:http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: this site you had provided doesn't solve my purpose. anyways thanks!